# Algorithm to pick best chance of game outcome

Tags: c#, math

Let's say we have multiple value combined with a time left, take the following list for example:

```
220 - 1 minute left
150 - 2 minutes left
600 - 13 minutes left
180 - 2 hours left
540 - 1 hour left
400 - 1.5 hours left
```

The time left rarely exceeds two hours, but can in theory be anything. So let's say that the maximum time left is unknown at the time. These values increase more or less constant with time. The goal is to order the list based on the **lowest** value by time. In the example list, I would prefer a result close to:

```
150 - 2 minutes left
220 - 1 minute left
180 - 2 hours left
400 - 1.5 hours left
540 - 1 hour left
600 - 13 minutes left
```

I'm not good at maths and I'm not entirely sure what would be the best way to sort it like this. Basically, the time should be factored in to a certain degree in order to determine the best order.

I'll elaborate a bit more on this subject as it seems the questioning was unclear. The values represent a number of bids on a certain item (food, wood, etc). I would like to show a sorting based on the chance a user gets during entering. For example, some items don't get bid often and as the items are given away for free they would still get a chance to win something.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the order is like that?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I've added a description to elaborate on it.

Comment: do you know that you don't even know what you want?

Comment: I do know what I want, is there anything still unclear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your values in a `List<T>` with `T` being a `class` with an `int Score` property and a `TimeSpan TimeLeft` property.

Then you can do the following:

```
var sortedList = originalList.OrderBy(x => x.Score + x.TimeLeft.TotalMinutes).ToList();
```

Based on your example (order value in brackets):

```
150 - 2 minutes left (152)
220 - 1 minute left (221)
180 - 2 hours left (300)
400 - 1.5 hours left (490)
540 - 1 hour left (600)
600 - 13 minutes left (613)
```

Comment: That would not work correctly, see the example.

Comment: Updated for a better algorithm - convert TimeLeft into minutes and add to Score for the sort.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that's closest to what I have right now. I'm not entirely sure why I asked in the first place. It's pretty easy as I also have information about the bids per minute so I can just take that and multiply with the time left.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

1. use `Regex` to get the time
2. convert time to minutes (or sec, whatever it could be)
3. sort by the converted time

Comment: I already have the time as a DateTime object. Sorting by converted time would not solve the problem.